# Diff SVC - Talknet Training.ipynb Colaboratory

Tags: artificial-intelligence, diff, svc

I have this link where you can check this whole thing: [https://colab.research.google.com/github/justinjohn0306/TalkNET-colab/blob/main/TalkNet_Training.ipynb?authuser=2#scrollTo=nfSawDUD5tqv&uniqifier=1 ]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2eYaCclnU0

So, my problem is that in Step 3, I have this error code and don't know what to do:

AssertionError Traceback (most recent call last)  in  11 output_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/talknet/name_of_character" #@param {type:"string"} 12 assert os.path.exists(dataset), "Cannot find dataset" ---> 13 assert os.path.exists(train_filelist), "Cannot find training filelist" 14 assert os.path.exists(val_filelist), "Cannot find validation filelist" 15 if not os.path.exists(output_dir): AssertionError: Cannot find training filelist

Can someone help me please? I uploaded the chopped vocals and the .txt file with the lyrics. And I don't know why can't it see it. :( I have the text file like this:
2.wav∣Take my hand.
3.wav∣Why are we.
And so on... I put everything in a .zip file and uploaded it to the Drive.
I chopped the vocals in Audacity and export it with labels.
And then started to do everything as shown in the video.

Comment: You need to make sure the path is correct, e.g. "/content/drive/My Drive/Voice-Cloning/datasets/MyDataset/dataset.zip"
The Zip should be a standard zip containing a file called "metadata.csv" and a folder called "wavs" with wavs inside it - DO NOT zip the parent folder (i.e. when you unzip, you should end up with the wavs and metadata files directly, not a folder containing them.